# Easily navigate around a rotated object

Tags: modeling, workflow, shortcut, navigation

I find it kind of cumbersome to edit an object that has been rotated. I know I can set the navigation to „local“ to make things easier, but then I still cannot use numpad <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, etc. to easily jump between the views. Is there a way to use these shortcuts on a rotated object or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the default keymap it’s <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad</kbd>.

To align a view to an object’s local axis without <kbd>Shift</kbd>, tick the 'Align Active' option in *Preferences* → *Keymap* → *3D View* → *View Axis*

[image]

Comment: huh. had no idea this existed, thanks :)

Comment: oops.. I just saw it´s included in the default keymap (2.9.5) with Shift + Numpad. Answer edited.

Comment: Shift + numpad doesn't seem to work in Edit mode though, from what I undertand he's asking for Edit mode

Comment: Here it also works in edit mode (Windows 10, 2.93.5). The alignment is done to the active geomtry.

Comment: @relaxed, oh you're right it works if you select a face in Face Select mode